# mvc / jquery best way to generate a bracket style image or view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to generate an image or an html page where the users can click on the matches and edit it. I am not sure if using jquery/javascript (or maybe css) is the best way or should i just generate a table style setup where i have a list of dropdowns so users can edit their matches..
something like this but not a jpeg.

http://www.printyourbrackets.com/5teamsingleelimination.html

any advise? I really am in limbo as to where i should focus my efforts on how to generate this.

Thanks much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You could check out raphael js for these kind of things. It's a vector library to output vectors crossbrowser. They do have some demo's of user-editable vectors:
[Raphaël js' home on the web](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: oh this is awesome, thanks i'll look around and see what it can offer!

Answer (score 0):

You could try: http://erik5388.github.com/jquery.gracket.js/